# How do make a H1 move down page whilst page scrolls?

Tags: html

Hi Im looking to make a heading keep its position at the top of the page whilst the user scrolls down or up. How do I go about doing this.

Many Thanks

:)

Comment: `h1 { position: fixed }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
h1 {
 position:fixed;
}
```

However, it will be better to give your h1 tag a class name.

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="heading">Your header title. </h1>
```

and then in your **CSS** code:

```
.heading {
  position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Good markup will only include one `h1` element per page anyway.

Comment: How is this different from my answer? :-)

Comment: @ Marty True. But since the code hasn't been posted, I couldn't assume it has been made using markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CSS and add the class to the specific H1 element you wish to scroll with page. Applying the below to `h1 {position: fixed;}` will result in all H1 elements scrolling with page.

See Fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm4w4cry/1/)

```
.scrollH
{
    position: fixed;
}
```

To better track the position, javascript will be required.

Answer (score 0):

the body (or parent tag), should be set `position: relative` in css, and that H1 tag should be: `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`